# Convert ascii (hexadecimal digits) into int Ca2 on MIPS assembler

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm thinking about how should use "andi" operations for getting Ca2 translation from a ascii NULL terminated (ascii it's a integer hexadecimal). Converting ascii to int it's easy, comparing "lb" with 48 or 57, applying mul 10 and later save it in "v0". But i have no idea making about. Some idea?

Thanks a lot.

Here the code im using to convert ascii to unsigned int:

http://pastebin.com/K5bEmJBZ

Comment: Could you explain what is `Ca2`?

Comment: Complement to 2:  0111 its 7 maxium positive integer, 1000 will be '0', 1001 will be -1, etc... Any number starting on 1 its negative.

Comment: That's not 2's complement, because then `1000` would be `-8`, `1001` would be `-7` and `-1` would be `1111`.

Comment: True, maybe i had explained bad. Your answer its the idea.

Comment: So, if you already have an unsigned converter,use that, and if the input starts with a minus sign, negate the value by subtracting from zero. Easy.

Comment: i uploaded the code converting ascii to unsigned int

Comment: Do you have any trouble with doing what I said?

Comment: i don't undestarstant why i should substracte from zero...

Comment: Because `0-x` is `-x`.

Comment: Yeah, but only if the input starts with a `-` sign of course.

Comment: i think that is not the solution to my problem. Because in the first code, i'm getting integer from string with a unsigned decimal. But now i have a string with a 2's complement hexadecimal integer to convert a decimal (unsigned or signed).

Comment: If your input is already hex digits then your question is really about hex conversion, and you don't really care about 2's complement. Make sure you convert the digits properly and multiply by 16 instead of 10 (you can do that by shifting).

Comment: how many positions should shitf to left? 4 or 8?

Comment: ok and later do a or bit a bit?                                        andi $t2,$t2,0x0F #addi $t2, $t2, -48
sll $v0, $v0, 4    #v0 *= 10
or $v0, $v0, $t2    #v0 += str[i]-'0'